# How to start Server Application on Windows

Tags: java, service, websocket, java-server

I created a simple Client-Server Application, which is working fine.
The server is listening to a port and  then starts a thread for the job.
At the moment the only way (outside the IDE) is, to kill the java.exe to stop the server.
Both example classes are very stripped-down.

Main Class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  MultiThreadedServer server = new MultiThreadedServer(9000);
  new Thread(server).start();
}
```

MultiThreadedServer Class:

```
public class MultiThreadedServer implements Runnable {

  protected int serverPort = 9000;
  protected ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
  protected Thread runningThread = null;
  protected ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Options.getInstance().getThreadCount());

  public MultiThreadedServer(int port) {
    this.serverPort = port;
  }

  public void run() {
    synchronized (this) {
      this.runningThread = Thread.currentThread();
    }
    openServerSocket();
    while (true) {
      Socket clientSocket;
      try {
        clientSocket = this.serverSocket.accept();
      } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error accepting client connection", e);
      }

      try {
        this.threadPool.execute(new WorkerRunnable(clientSocket, Constants.appName + " Thread"));
      } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }

  private void openServerSocket() {
    try {
      this.serverSocket = new ServerSocket(this.serverPort);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Cannot open port " + serverPort, e);
    }
  }
}
```

I am wondering, what is the best practice to start the server application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it on my own.
I´ve created a windows batch script, which processes some pre-requirements and starts the server application.
And with nssm [nssm](http://nssm.cc/) I have installed this batch file as windows service. Not the server application is controllable by windows services.